# SDL Tridion R&D feedback session on June 27: Do you have feedback on page regions?

Tags: discussion

The concept of page regions was introduced through SmartTarget on page template level and has been built on by the Experience Manager.

SDL Tridion R&D is currently working on how to expose page regions in content manager and the UIs. As this is a topic that affects the way we implement Websites, we will be hosting an information and feedback session on 27 June 2013 from 16:00 to 18:00 CET.

The details of the session will be announced in the [SDL Tridion Pulse Linkedin group](http://www.linkedin.com/groups/SDL-Tridion-Pulse-2783409/about).

I look forward to your feedback.

Comment: Davina, I have tagged this as a featured post so it will show up in the Community Bulletin in the right rail of the main Tridion SE site. Once you have the details of the session would you please edit your question to include them?