# Should we close posts made to Tridion Meta about specific events once those events have passed?

Tags: discussion

We have some questions posted here in meta: [SDL Tridion Community Webinar (will be recorded)](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217/sdl-tridion-community-webinar-will-be-recorded) and [SDL Tridion R&D feedback session on June 27: Do you have feedback on page regions?](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179/sdl-tridion-rd-feedback-session-on-june-27-do-you-have-feedback-on-page-region) that are tied to specific events and would seem to have short life spans.

Once events like these have taken place should we close these to minimize the long term clutter here on Tridion Meta?

Comment: I don't see a problem closing event announcements unless they have more long-term information. How do closed meta questions look like in the list?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's a big enough problem to do anything about so far. I'd say just treat them as normal questions. I don't think there would be anything wrong with "I had a great time" comments etc?

Comment: I agree with Rob, it's meta, and discussions don't really seem to run wild here, so I would say no need to close them either.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say sure if we can close them without leaving a note that discourages these types of announcements (they're still okay, right?).

Alternatively would it make sense to update them to remove dates and maybe leave follow-up information? Might we re-use the same questions again (e.g. for the next community webinar)?